# What is the prefix Fluent signify in the WPF control name "Fluent:RibbonWindow"?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In FluentRibbon project, the XAML file contains:

```
<Fluent:RibbonWindow xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

I know that `RibbonWindow` is a class (derived from WPF `Window` class).  It's the `Fluent:` prefix that I don't understand.

The same type of construct is also used by MahMetro like so:

```
<Metro:MetroWindow x:Class="FluentTest.MahMetroWindow"
```

What does the prefix signify in the above cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the namespace those controls/types live in. Some namespaces are included automatically when Xaml is converted to C#, but anything new that you bring in (either from 3rd party libraries or your own application) has to be explicit.

```
<UserControl xmlns:customControls="using:MyNamespace.CustomControls"

    ... more declarations ...

    <customControls:MySpecialPanel />
</UserControl>
```